# res.sendFile() is not rendering in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been struggling with this for a few days. Anyone have any ideas? On click of a log in button I'm authorizing the user, generating a token, storing the token in cookies, then using the token in headers of a request to render to the homepage. I get no errors on the res.sendFile() and I've done some ordering with console.log() to make sure the order of events is proper. I can't figure out what's going wrong. Additionally, I know the res.sendFile works because in postman if I call the api route to take me to the homepage with the bearer token, the HTML is returned in the postman response. Below is the code - any help is appreciated!

index.js -->

```
document.getElementById('loginSubmit').addEventListener('click' , () => {
  var un = document.getElementById('username').value;
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    "username": un,
    "password": document.getElementById('password').value
  });
  document.cookie = 'user_name='+un;
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.responseType = 'json'
  req.withCredentials = true;

  req.open("POST","~/users/authenticate", true);
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  req.send(data);
  
  req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if(this.readyState === 4 && req.status == 200) {
          
    //save token to cookies
    var obj = req.response.token;
    document.cookie = 'user_token='+obj;
    console.log(document.cookie)

    //redirect home
    var req2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req2.open("GET","http://localhost:4000/homepage",true);
    req2.setRequestHeader("Authorization",'Bearer '+obj);
    req2.send(); 
    }
});
```

server.js -->

```
app.use('/users', require('./users/users.controller'));
app.use('/homepage', authorize(), (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile('/homepage.html', {root: publicDir}),function(err) { if (err) console.log(err);}
});
```

In postman, if I get '/homepage' with the bearer token stored in the cookie and passed in the request header, I get the homepage.html as the response. But in browser, I get no error but also don't get the '/hompage.html' page. Everything else works as expected, user is authenticated, token generated, stored in cookie, etc. Verified the call is actually going through via console.log() and the request is correct.

Comment: The AJAX code doesn't render anything. The first one just sets a cookie, the second one doesn't have a `readystatechange` listener, so it doesn't do anything with the response.

Comment: Don't use AJAX for `homepage`. Use `window.location = "/homepage"`

Comment: the code under `//redirect home` does not do what your comment says it does. It's just another AJAX request, whose response you ignore.

Comment: @JaromandaX apologies if this is dumb, I'm new to front end. Shouldn't the response from server side sending the file to the browser be enough? Do I have to catch the response and then use window.location on client side?

Comment: The request just returns a file. The browser dosnt do anything at first since the file could be anything (pdf, img, or html). If you check in the dev tools (F12) you can probably see that the file is actually being returned.

Comment: In case you want to render the page you need to redirect the user to the url. When you open a new page in you browser by url the path ist requested from the server and then rendered. You can do this by setting `window.location` or you can replace the html of you page with the html in the response. I would recommend against replacing html since its more hacky and opens up your page to XSS attacks.

Comment: How do you check if the user is authenticated? If your only looking at the `Authorization` header that wont work. Since when you open the page you can only run code after the page was loaded. Therefor you also need to check for the auth cookie eg. `user_token`

Comment: @VincentMenzel you're right the file is being served. I can see it in the network tab. I have an auth middleware that is checking the cookie against the DB secret and attaching a user object. I believe the thing I was missing is that I need to catch the response from the api and redirect based on that. I incorrectly thought that the res.sendFile() from the server side would force the client side to render. New to front end obviously...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case helps anyone down the line, I was just missing the listener on the 2nd request as Barmar pointed out. Here's the correct code on index.js.

```
    document.getElementById('loginSubmit').addEventListener('click' , () => {
      var un = document.getElementById('username').value;
      var data = JSON.stringify({
        "username": un,
        "password": document.getElementById('password').value
      });
      document.cookie = 'user_name='+un;
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.responseType = 'json'
      req.withCredentials = true;

      req.open("POST","http://localhost:4000/users/authenticate", true);
      req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      req.send(data);)


      req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if(this.readyState === 4 && req.status == 200) {
        
        //save token to cookies
        var obj = req.response.token;
        document.cookie = 'user_token='+obj;

        //redirect home
        var req2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req2.open("GET",~/homepage",true);
        req2.setRequestHeader("Authorization",'Bearer '+obj);
        req2.send();

/// this is the piece I was missing like an idiot
        
req2.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
          if(req2.readyState === 4 && req2.status == 200) {
            window.location = 'homepage.html'
          }
        })
         
       
        
        }

        
      });

      

    })
```